# How can i get the tcp dynamicport

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

How can I get the tcp dynamicport with C# .Net Core 6？

like the result of command :

```
"netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp" in windows

C:\Users\XXX>netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

Protocol tcp dynamic port range
---------------------------------
Startup port : 49152
Number of ports : 16384
```

need the value of "Startup port" and "Number of ports"

I have checked the relevant materials of Microsoft, and found no relevant API and class provided

Comment: You can always execute 'cmd.exe' programmatically with your required command as an argument and get the output which will be the ports.

Comment: You need to provide code block for the cmdlets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "netsh",
        Arguments = "int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    }
};

process.Start();
```

The code uses the **System.Diagnostics** namespace to execute the "**netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp**" command and print the output to the console.

See [this github post for the full code](https://github.com/Jabsal/NetshCommand/blob/main/Program.cs)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure you can, I think you have to call netsh directly, which will only work on windows but if that's an option, maybe you could have a look at https://github.com/rpetz/SharpNetSH and extend it to your needs?

Comment: This dependency does not seem to implement Netsh.Interface, and it has not been updated for five years